# How to install dlib in linux offline?

Tags: linux, boost, cmake, pip, dlib

I have a linux server can not link the Internet and I wand to install dlib in my anaconda enviroment. But I do not know how to install cmake and boost for python? can any one help me? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Dlib directly without cmake and visual studio

First Download the CMake installer and install it from 'https://cmake.org/download/'

Add CMake executable path to the Enviroment Variables:
set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin"

Then "pip install CMake"

Install Visual Studio build tools from 'https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#'

In Visual Studio 2017 go to the Individual Components tab, Visual C++ Tools for Cmake, and check the checkbox under the "Compilers, build tools and runtimes" section.

The  at last "pip install dlib"

It definitely works., have a try :)

Comment: so you mean linux with commanline can not install dlib?

Comment: Try this, it may helpful to you

https://github.com/mhaghighat/dlib_ubuntu_install